# JObject and DotLiquid

Tags: c#, liquid, dotliquid

I'm working on a REST mock service. I use DotLiquid. I want to parse POST body into a object from XML and JSON.

DotLiquid works with anonymous types, like

```
var input = new
{
    Body = new { Foos = new[] { new{ Bar = "OneBar" }, new { Bar = "TwoBar" } }  }
};

var template = Template.Parse(@"{% for item in Body.Foos %}
{{ item.Bar }}
{% endfor %}");
Console.WriteLine(template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(input)));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

> OneBar
>
> TwoBar

But doing the same with `JObject` does not output anything

```
var json = "{ 'Foos': [{ 'Bar': 'OneBar' }, { 'Bar': 'TwoBar' }] }";

var input = new
{
    Body = JObject.Parse(json)
};

var template = Template.Parse(@"{% for item in Body.Foos %}
{{ item.Bar }}
{% endfor %}");
Console.WriteLine(template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(input)));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is no direct support for JSON in DotLiquid

Get newtonsoft.json library and deserialize json first; something like this

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonObject, expConverter);
```

`Expando` implements `IDictionary` supported by DotLiquid. Or, do the list

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);
```

Comment: What would "expConverter" be?

Comment: @RafaelSimonelli see documentation https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm